# Homeomorphisms between closed surfaces and induced maps on fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am currently working on a problem and I have solved all the differents points except for one, that I have reduced to the following exercise which I could not solve:

*Show that two homeomorphisms between closed surfaces (in my case, between tori) are homotopic if and only if they induce the same map on the fundamental group(s).*

I have found (in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, Proposition 1B.9 page 90) a proof of what seems to be a more general fact, but since I don't know much about algebraic topology I wonder if one could give a more elementary proof in the special case of this exercise. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For tori it's ok, but in general you have to take care of the basepoints. Can you prove at least one direction of this statement?